# c# list each in json array

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I'm new at this and have figured out some of the json parsing.
My json response from the api looks like this.

```
{
  count: 100,
  value: [{
        id: "03dd9f56-108f-4e8f-b92e-93df05717464",
        name: "IIBTest",
        url: "http://xxx:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects/03dd9f56-108f-4e8f-b92e-93df05717464",
        state: "wellFormed",
        revision: 14434848,
        visibility: "private"
      },
      {
        id: "b7e15034-fc8f-4f7e-866a-cb06f44b12ed",
        name: "MS Project POC",
        description: "POC for MS Project with TFS",
        url: "http://xxx/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects/b7e15034-fc8f-4f7e-866a-cb06f44b12ed",
        state: "wellFormed",
        revision: 14434955,
        visibility: "private"
      },
      {
        id: "59e06621-c5f5-4fd1-9c55-1def541b99d9",
        name: "WorkflowReporting",
        url: "http://xxx/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects/59e06621-c5f5-4fd1-9c55-1def541b99d9",
        state: "wellFormed",
        revision: 14434591,
        visibility: "private"
      },
      {
        id: "78a802f0-5eee-4bcb-bde9-a764e46f56db",
        name: "iSolutions",
        url: "http://xxx/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects/78a802f0-5eee-4bcb-bde9-a764e46f56db",
        state: "wellFormed",
        revision: 14434639,
        visibility: "private"
      },
      {
        id: "1f20506a-63a5-486a-a857-fec64d7486a6",
        name: "Training",
        description: "MLITS Training and Learning",
        url: "http://xxx/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects/1f20506a-63a5-486a-a857-fec64d7486a6",
        state: "wellFormed",
        revision: 14434676,
        visibility: "private"
      },
```

and so on I have 100 projects in the collection.  In my code I am simply trying to console.writeline the name:  My code looks like this.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
var projectUri = "http://xxx/tfs/defaultcollection/_apis/projects?api-version=3.0";
wc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
string jsonProjectCollection = wc.DownloadString(projectUri);

var project = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Project>(jsonProjectCollection);
var projectname = project.value[0].name;
int count = project.count;

Console.WriteLine(count);
Console.WriteLine(projectname);
```

the projectname is only giving me the name in that first array, how can I get it to step through each array and print a list of each projectname.  Sorry I'm new at this so any help would be great.

Comment: Presumably `project.value` is a list or an array, so use `foreach (var entry in project.value)` etc.

Comment: Also add the Project class in the question

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, not sure what I was thinking here is how.

```
           for (int intCounter = 0; intCounter < count; intCounter ++)
        {
            var projectname = project.value[intCounter].name;
            Console.WriteLine(projectname);
        }
```

Comment: Why use a `for` loop relying on a separate `count` value when you can just use `foreach` over `project.value`?

Comment: @JonSkeet - Both are valid approaches. Technically, the for loop is faster, so that's one reason why.

Comment: @ScubaSteve: Without knowing the type of `project.value`, you can't say which is faster. Beyond that, any difference in performance is almost *certainly* going to be insignificant, and I would strongly encourage the OP to write the simplest code that works to start with - which is far more likely to be a `foreach` loop.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Yes but this is an example, we don't know the end use. It could be running on n rows. Further, a for loop is first year CS, it's hardly more complex than a for each. You could argue a for each is more complex, as there's more going on under the hood.

Comment: @ScubaSteve: There's more going on under the hood, but it's simpler code to read. That's why it's in the language to start with. The index here is just an implementation detail - unless it's used for a purpose *other* than "getting to each entry", I would content that `foreach` describes the intention of the code more clearly than a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it makes more sense, and is more useful to deserialize and retain the object structure. The object inside value is an JSON array. You can use the Json.NET JArray class to store what's inside value.

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm

So, deserialize -> pull the array out of the object structure -> iterate through said array.

```
//pseudo code ahead
foreach(project p in projects)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.name);
}
```

Alternatively, accessing the object directly, you can do a simple for loop. Note, you can also do a for each on an array as well in C#.

```
for(int i = 0; i < project.count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(project.value[i].name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var projectCollection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Project>(jsonProjectCollection);
var projects= projectCollection.value;
int count = projectCollection .count;
foreach(var project in projects)
{
   Console.WriteLine(project.name);
}
Console.WriteLine(count);
Console.WriteLine(projectname);
```